# SqLite composite Select from a Select statement

Tags: sqlite

How to perform a composite select statement from another select in sqlite? Is it possible to add condition in WHERE clause using a computed column inside the select?

I have following working statement

```
SELECT detection_id,
      evalround_id,
      min(detection.posright, labelgt.posright) - max(detection.posleft, labelgt.posleft) + 1 
        AS overlap_width
FROM detection, labelgt
WHERE 
      labelgt.timestamp = detection.timestamp
```

I would like to add condition on the computed 'overlap_width'

```
 AND overlap_width > 0
```

which unfortunately ends with an error 'Error while executing query: no such column: overlap_width'.

I tried to create a composite statement,

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM
        (
         SELECT  detection_id,
              evalround_id,
              min(detection.posright, labelgt.posright) - max(detection.posleft, labelgt.posleft) + 1 
                AS overlap_width
            -- overlap_width * overlap_height AS overlap_area
        FROM detection, labelgt
        WHERE 
                labelgt.timestamp = detection.timestamp 
        ) AS IT
    WHERE
        IT.overlap_width > 0
```

which ens up with an 'Error while executing query: no such column: detection.posleft'. But there is a valid column detection.posleft in the table.

Comment: [Works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/af6c1/2); your example is not what you actually tried to execute.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite Support it, you can have where condition on your inner column. i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM (select min(b.cold1-c.col2) as tid, *  from table1 b , table2 c )   where tid =  -538
```

Comment: I use SqliteStudio, executing statement 'select detection_id from detection where detection_id>9000' successfully, but statement 'select detection_id as did from detection where did>9000' fails (no such column: did).